# How to draw a segment of a circle in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

**Context**
I try to draw pie chart for statistic in my game. I'm using Cocos2d-x ver.3.8.1. Size of the game is important, so I won't to use third-party frameworks to create pie charts.
**Problem**
I could not find any suitable method in Cocos2d-x for drawing part of the circle.
**I tried to do**
I tried to find a solution to this problem in Internet, but without success.
As is known, sector of a circle = triangle + segment. So, I tried to use the method `drawSegment()` from `DrawNode` also. 
Although it has parameter `radius` ("The segment radius" written in [API reference](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.9/dd/d6a/classcocos2d_1_1_draw_node.html#a96b1fba6c02b6192b97bf0a0e06331d1)), radius affects only the thickness of the line.
`drawSegment()` method draw a simple line, the thickness of which is set by a method call.
**Question**
Please prompt me, how can I draw a segment or a sector of a circle in Cocos2d-x?
Any advice will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the one of the ways to draw a sector of a circle in Cocos2d-X is the way to use `drawPolygon` on `DrawNode`. I wrote little sample.

```
void drawSector(cocos2d::DrawNode* node, cocos2d::Vec2 origin, float radius, float angle_degree,
                cocos2d::Color4F fillColor, float borderWidth, cocos2d::Color4F bordercolor,
                unsigned int num_of_points = 100)
{
  if (!node)
  {
    return;
  }

  const cocos2d::Vec2 start = origin + cocos2d::Vec2{radius, 0};
  const auto angle_step = 2 * M_PI * angle_degree / 360.f / num_of_points;
  std::vector<cocos2d::Point> circle;

  circle.emplace_back(origin);
  for (int i = 0; i <= num_of_points; i++)
  {
    auto rads = angle_step * i;
    auto x = origin.x + radius * cosf(rads);
    auto y = origin.y + radius * sinf(rads);
    circle.emplace_back(x, y);
  }

  node->drawPolygon(circle.data(), circle.size(), fillColor, borderWidth, bordercolor);
}
```

This is the function to calculate the position of edge point of circle and draw polygon. If you want to use it, you need to call like following,

```
auto canvas = DrawNode::create();
drawSector(canvas, cocos2d::Vec2(400, 400), 100, 60, cocos2d::Color4F::GREEN, 2, cocos2d::Color4F::BLUE, 100);
this->addChild(triangle);
```

[image: The result]

The result would be like this. I think the code will help your problem.